# How to specify the elements that the forms.select() must show in django

Tags: python, django, forms, model

i am developing a project with django, and i have a little problem.

I am trying to make a forms.py, and i have a widget form with 'forms.select()'.

I just want to know what can i do if i want to specify what elements of that widget should show:

This is a part from my forms.py:

```
fields = [
            ...
            'id_clasificacion_fk',
            ...
            ]
        labels = {

            ...
            'id_clasificacion_fk': 'Clasificación del producto',
            ...
        }
        widgets = {
            ...
            'id_clasificacion_fk': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            ...
        }
```

As you can see, i have the widget 'id_clasification_fk' but it shows me all the elements that are in 'id_clasificacion_fk'.

And you just want to show the elements that have "existencia=True".

This is my models.py:

```
class Articulo(models.Model):
    ...
    existencia=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
    #llaves 
    id_clasificacion_fk=models.ForeignKey('Clasificacion', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_clasificacion_fk')

    def __str__(self):
        return "("+str(self.id)+") " + self.nombre_producto
```

Again, i just want to show the elements from id_clasificacion_fk that have the "existencia" set to True, and just these.

If anyone could help me with this i appreciate.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
queryset=Classification.objects.filter(existencia=True)
```

where this goes depends on where you want to specify it and whether you're using a model form.  You should be able to define it when you define the field or within the form's `init` function or when you specify the form in the view

For example, inside a view you would have

```
form = MyForm()
form.fields['id_clasificacion_fk'].queryset=Classification.objects.filter(existencia=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, can you show me an example?. I have used "Classification.objects.filter(existencia=True)" but in the views. I want to do it inside of the form, because i am using a form inside of the template.